# Mono ASP.NET 1.1 Support

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, asp.net-1.1

I haven't found anything about it on the web, does ***mono*** support ***ASP.NET 1.1***
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it does not.  ASP.NET 2.0 and above only.

Answer (score 4):

[Mono supports ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) which is mostly a superset of asp.net 1.1. It should work. Are there particular asp.net 1.1 only things you want to use?

Comment: its a very complex site, more than 200 solutions. we use a lot of specific 1.1 stuff (like email and microsoft extended controls for 1.1)